# How to package a browser plugin and a gui app in a snap package

Tags: firefox, application-development, browser, ubuntu-core

My app is a gui app (qt) and a browser plugin. The plugin is used only for firefox. When the user clicks a button I want to open my gui-app.

I would like to use a snap package to do this, but I can not find how to package a browser plugin. I need that the plugin is available on reload of the page.

Other solution can be to not use a plugin, but I can not find how to configure firefox to open a specific app with a click. I should be done by the app installer.

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently offer a way for snaps to integrate with the the browser, I'm afraid.

This is probably going to happen at some point (at least in the sense you seem to want, i.e. hand particular URLs off to particular apps), but I couldn't hazard a guess as to when.

Comment: I asked in IRC a couple of days ago about something like intents in android. Some developers told me that the intents protocol will be added in the future. Do you know if it is true?

Comment: intents might be the wrong name for it, but yes, inasmuch as the ubuntu phone has this, snappy ubuntu personal will have it.